# sf::Text doesn't display?

Tags: c++, text, sfml

I'm trying to display a sf::Text on my window and it doesn't work and i don't understand why !

Here's an example of the code:
constructor

```
timerText.setFont(getFont());
timerText.setString("test");
timerText.setCharacterSize(70);
timerText.setColor(Color::Red);
```

getFont() :

```
Font& Timer::getFont(){
Font font;
if(!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf")){
    cout << "font not loaded" << endl;
}
return font;
```

}

draw() :

```
timerText.setPosition(Vector2f(center.x - 8, center.y - size.y/2 + 12));
window.draw(timerText);
```

All my other draws work perfectly and i haven't error when i'm loading the font.
Sorry for my English and thank you for your help !

Comment: Why are you returning reference to local variable? It is undefined behaviour. `font` is local inside `getFont` method, it cannot work.

Comment: I thought there was something strange about it. I still don't understand very well how references work.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by adding a private variable sf::Font in my class and by swaping
setFont(getFont()); 
by 
font.loadFromFile(fontFile); 
setFont(font);

I still doesn't understand my error but now it works.

Answer (score 0):

at `getFont()`, you load a font into local variable in stack memory. When the function returns, it is deleted automatically..

You should move or allocate it other place..

```
Font font;
Font& Timer::getFont(){
    if(!font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf")){
        cout << "font not loaded" << endl;
    }
    return font;
}
```